# Dividing an array column by its norm returns a null column

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

This runs the Gram–Schmidt algorithm on a square matrix.
The lines causing problems are the following

```py
R[j, j] = la.norm(Q[:, j])
a = Q[:,j]
b = a/R[j,j]
Q[:,j] = Q[:,j]/R[j,j]
```

By running these lines the column `Q[:,j]` is set to `0` instead of the correct value. This doesn't happen if I use a temporary variable. How is this possible?
The full code

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mod_gramschmidt(X):
    n = X.shape[0]
    R = np.zeros((n, n))
    Q = X.copy()

    for j in range(n):
        R[j, j] = la.norm(Q[:, j])
        a = Q[:, j]
        b = a / R[j, j]
        Q[:, j] = Q[:, j] / R[j, j]
        A = R[j, (j + 1) :]
        B = Q[:, j].T
        R[j, (j + 1) :] = Q[:, j].T @ X[:, (j + 1) :]
        Q[:, (j + 1) :] = Q[:, (j + 1) :] - Q[:, j] @ R[j, (j + 1) :]
```

I run the code with the following input:

```py
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,5,4]])
print(mod_gramschmidt(A))
```

Comment: "this doesn't happen if I use a temporary variable." Please show the code that works as expected.

Comment: It's more related to integer  type of matrix that you use, make the matrix a float one then division does not give 0 anymore. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64753403/multiplication-of-an-integer-numpy-array-by-a-float-number). But even if you resolve this part, the algorithm does not work properly, are you sure about the rest part of the function?

Comment: Why the algorithm contains `a`, `b`, `A` and `B`? Seems like they have no role in the algorithm...

Answer (score 0):

After

- dropping unnecessary `a`, `b`, `A`, and `B` variables,
- fixing matrix multiplication `Q[:, j].reshape((-1,1)) @ R[j, (j + 1) :].reshape((1,-1))` by reshaping vectors `Q[:, j]` and `R[j, (j + 1) :]` into `n x 1`and `1 x m` matrices,
- adding `return` statement

the presented algorithm reads as

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mod_gramschmidt(X):
    n = X.shape[0]
    R = np.zeros((n, n))
    Q = X.copy()
    
    for j in range(n):
        R[j, j] = la.norm(Q[:, j])
        Q[:, j] = Q[:, j] / R[j, j]
        R[j, (j + 1) :] = Q[:, j].T @ X[:, (j + 1) :]
        Q[:, (j + 1) :] = Q[:, (j + 1) :] - Q[:, j].reshape((-1,1)) @ R[j, (j + 1) :].reshape((1,-1))
    return Q
```

Now applying this algorithm to integer matrix

```py
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,5,4]])
print(mod_gramschmidt(A))
```

yields

```
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]
```

However, applying the same algorithm to float matrix

```
A = np.array([[1.,2.,3.],[4.,5.,6.],[7.,5.,4.]])
print(mod_gramschmidt(A))
```

yields

```
[[ 0.12309149  0.52015649  0.84515425]
 [ 0.49236596  0.70741282 -0.50709255]
 [ 0.86164044 -0.47854397  0.16903085]]
```

If inside the algorithm the integer matrix are casted `astype(float)`

```py
def mod_gramschmidt(X):
    n = X.shape[0]
    R = np.zeros((n, n)).astype(float)
    Q = X.copy().astype(float)
    
    ...
```

then the error connected to integer matrix calculations does not appear.