# Multiplication of an integer numpy array by a float number

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array containing integer values. If I multiply once the whole matrix to a float number the result is a float matrix, but if I multiply column by column though a for loop, it gives only the  integer parts.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
B = A

print("Multiplication as a whole matrix:")
A = 0.5*A
print(A)

for i in range(A.shape[1]):
    B[:,i] = 0.5*B[:,i]
    
print("Multiplication column by column:")
print(B)
```

If I change even only one element of the matrix to a float number (e.g. 1 to 1.0), both method gives the true result. I would like to know the underlying reason for that.

Answer (score 4):

```
A = 0.5*A
```

Changes the whole array.  When `A.__rmul__(0.5)` is called by the interpreter, it sees `0.5` is a `float` and thus creates a new `A` with `dtype = float`

```
for i in range(A.shape[1]):
    B[:,i] = 0.5*B[:,i]
```

Now, we're trying to read back `B` piecewise.  But even though `0.5*B[:, i]` is an array of floats, `B` is still `dtype = int`, so it casts the `float`s to `int` to fit in the existing `B` data structure.

Setting "even only one element of the matrix to a float" sets the whole array to `dtype = float`, and then casting to `int` will stop.

Comment: To be precise, it doesn't *convert* it *creates a new array*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga agreed